# Cors error even though I have already enable cors on my server app

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, rest, cors

I keep receiving this error message

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'SERVER' from origin 'CLIENT' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and this is how I put the cors middleware on my server

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const router = require("./routes")
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(cors({origin: "*"}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({}))
app.use(express.json())

app.use("/", router)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I tried to set the cors to all origin and the error still persists

I put my server app on aws and client on firebase. the rest api works fine if I send the request using postman or hosting the server locally

I've tried checking the url request and checking all over internet, where it only show up if I haven't set up the cors middlewares, which I already did and yet I still get the error

Comment: Show the relevant client code.